# MDX Case Statement With Multiple Criteria in single "When"

Tags: mdx, case-statement

I'm trying to consolidate the following MDX script as much as possible and was wondering if there is a way to merge the four Quarters (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) into a single line? Also, if you have any further ideas on how to simplify this, I am all ears!

```
Case [Period].CurrentMember
  When [Q1] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*4
  When [Q2] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*4
  When [Q3] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*4
  When [Q4] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*4
  When [Total Year] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])        
Else 
  [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*12
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Case 
  When [Period].CurrentMember =[Q1] or [Period].CurrentMember =[Q2] or [Period].CurrentMember =[Q3] or [Period].CurrentMember =[Q4]
  Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*4
   When [Period].CurrentMember =[Total Year] Then [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])        
Else 
  [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue] / ([CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load])*12
End
```

Below is another example based on adventure works which helps.

```
with member measures.test as 
case  
when 
[Product].[Subcategory].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) ="caps" 
or [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) ="chains" 
or [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) ="gloves" 
then 1 
when [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember.Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) ="Fenders" 
then 5
else 0 end 
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.test} on columns ,
[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there no way to pull out the "[Period].CurrentMember" so you don't have to repeat it multiple times throughout the code? Just curious from a learning perspective as I am new to this language.

Comment: @Chris Newman you can not remove the ".CurrentMember" from your query. Since the value of the measure depends on the current value of [Period]. Currentmember gets the member for which the measure is being calulate. For example take a look at the picture above. When the value of measure.test is calculated for "bike racks" the measure is able to calculate the value 0 but when the currentmember returns Fender the measure calulates 5. I hope i am able to explain why we need currentmember

Comment: You should be using "IS" not "=" when you do a statement like this "...currentmember = [Q2]". Did you even test?

Comment: @whytheq yes i did test. The results are present in the answer. Would you kindly elaborate the advantage of "IS" over "="

Comment: @MoazRub the first part of your answer says "Case When [Period].CurrentMember =[Q1]" .... did you test that ? That is not the way to test equality between a currentmember and a member - you need to use "IS". Testing equality of a member to a member using IS should always be quicker than extracting a typed property and comparing to a string.

Comment: @whytheq The part of code you are refering to was a copy paste from the question, so obviously i did not test it, it was just to convey the idea. But i follwed it up with a working example to explain the idea in detail. Now as far as "IS" performing better the extracting a typed property, my understanding is till I am not using unique name IS would basicly be translated to Caption property, so just by using IS alone the performance wont improve. However incase of unique name IS should perfore better.

Answer (score 0):

The `IS` operator is your friend here: I'm unsure if the `=` operator will even work and using `....Properties ("Member_Value",TYPED) ="caps"` is slow.

Also I've tried to use `IIF` which, in `MDX`, is usually faster than `CASE`

```
IIF(
      ( [Period].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Period].[Period].[Q1] ) 
   OR ( [Period].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Period].[Period].[Q1] ) 
   OR ( [Period].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Period].[Period].[Q1] ) 
   OR ( [Period].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Period].[Period].[Q1] ) 
   , DIVIDE(
         [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue]
        ,( [CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load] )*4
     )
   , IIF(
        ( [Period].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Period].[Period].[Total Year] )
        , DIVIDE(
             [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue]
            ,( [CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load] )
          )
        , DIVIDE(
             [Finance Charge and NSF Revenue]
            ,( [CXO_Average Total A/R]+[Average Total A/R - Normalized Load] )*12
          )
)
```

---

Edit

On more complex queries using IIF / IS will be quicker - this is the equivalent to MoazRubs AdvWrks script:

```
WITH 
MEMBER measures.test as 
IIF(   
  [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember IS  [Product].[Subcategory].[Caps]
  OR [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember IS  [Product].[Subcategory].[Chains] 
    OR [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember IS  [Product].[Subcategory].[Gloves] 
  , 1
    , IIF(
       [Product].[Subcategory].currentmember IS  [Product].[Subcategory].[Fenders] 
     ,5
         ,NULL
      )
) 
SELECT 
   {
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
            measures.test
        } ON 0,
[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] ON 1 
FROM 
[Adventure Works]
```

Comment: the "=" works just fine. I have edited my answer to add a snap of the result.

Comment: @MoazRub I know it works in your answer. I was talking about the use of "=" in the original question.

Comment: Thanks @whytheq! Great to know the IFF function is faster. Is there a reason you are using the Divide function instead of how I used the "/"?

Comment: @ChrisNewman no reason for using the DIVIDE function, I just find it more readable: personal preference. But using the IS operator is the most important part of my proposal.